# How to find if LightSpeed server is installed

Tags: server, apache2, lamp, find, vps

I have LAMP installed in a VPS. When I visit my domain, Apache responds. But every once in a while, LightSpeed responds, i.e. instead of showing the Apache web root, it shows the LightSpeed web root. But I can't find if/where LightSpeed is actually installed. Any idea how I can find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just open a terminal and type

```
lightspeed
```

I don't have it so the output is

```
The program 'lightspeed' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install lightspeed
```

If it is installed and you want to know where

```
dpkg --listfiles lightspeed
```

Will show where all files for light speed can be found.